# Automatically inserting filename & line number in logging statements of a C program

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, arm, c-preprocessor

I am writing a program for an embedded ARM processor in **C**. I would like to see the source filename and line number in the logging statements.

As the compiled code has no knowledge of line numbers and source files, I am looking for ways to have this inserted automatically before / during the compile process.

Are there any standard tools or compiler features that I can use for this?

I am using GCC.

For example:

This is what I would write in the source file:

```
log("<#filename#> <#linenumber#> : Hello World");
```

This is what would actually get compiled:

```
log("Foobar.c 225 : Hello World");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you'd do something like this:

```
// logging function
void log(const char * file, const int line, const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: %s\n", file, line, msg);
}

// logging macro - passes __FILE__ and __LINE__ to logging function
#define LOG(msg) do { log(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg) } while (0)
```

Then when you want to log something:

```
LOG("We made it to this point!");
```

which will then generate a log message such as:

```
foo.c:42: We made it to this point!
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is the purpose of while(0)?

Comment: `do { ... } while(0)` is just the canonical method of writing a macro that can be invoked as if it were a function without causing problems, e.g. when placed before an `else`. It's actually redundant in this case, as there is only a single statement, but it's a good habit to get into in case you later want to add more code to the macro.

Comment: Worth mentioning even though this question is for GCC: Visual Studio likes the format `file(line) : message`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx

Comment: @MooingDuck: yes, Microsoft always like to do things differently than the civilised world. ;-) I think the OP specifically mentioned that they are using gcc, but obviously the above technique can be tailored to your platform/compiler of choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard set of predefined macros as part of the preprocessor: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

The macros you want to use are `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` which are the file name and line numbers.